# Do different address spaces exist for RAM and ROM in a typical microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, eeprom, ram, rom

If a microcontroller has 16 bit address space from 0000H to FFFFH, will the RAM, I/O registers, memory mapped I/O and ROM(Flash/EEPROM) share the same address space linearly, or will there be a separate address space for ROM alone(like another 0000H to 1FFFH), or is it manufacturer dependent?

I guess I read lot of documents and confused myself into this. Please help.

Comment: It's best if you select a specific device, then read the datasheet, then ask here if it's not clear.

Comment: Typically there will be different non contiguous spaces because of address decoding limitations and device size discrepancies

Comment: This depends *entirely* on the device. For PIC, yes; ARM, no. And so on.

Comment: I would question the existence of a typical microcontroller

Comment: @pjc50 you cannot map three devices of different size continuously even if you have an ARM. Maybe the application will see continuous addresses because of rhe MMU but HW addresses cannot be continuous for diff. sizes

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami If the address decoder does a full subtraction instead of just checking the high-order bits of the address, you can. But *even* wihout this, you can, for example: 128kByte at 0x00000, 64k at 0x20000, 16k at 0x30000.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami - having a common address space does not require having a contiguous one.  Essentially, what it means is that some of the same software-level access methods (at minimum, a read) can be used.

Comment: Your first 12 words define a situation where everything must be memory-mapped into the same 16 bit address space.  How finely that is divided, is merely a question of how much logic you want to put in.  The Apple II split its space quite fine, despite its famously low chip count, so it was able to get 48K RAM(including 1-9K display buffer), 2K I/O, 2K bankable card memory, and 12K ROM.

Answer (score 6):

That is in fact the key difference between "von Neumann" and "Harvard" architectures. The first uses a single address space for everything, while the latter has separate address spaces for instructions (usually ROM) and data (usually RAM).

You can get microcontrollers with either architecture. Some implement a hybrid of the two.

Comment: That was a striking point! But how exactly would be a hybrid of the the two? Little more insight please..?

Comment: Some architectures (notably 8080 and derivatives) use separate address spaces for I/O

Comment: For example, the 8051 is a Harvard machine, but it has instructions that allow data to be moved from instruction space. Also, if you connect external memory to it, it's easy to"fold" the address spaces on top of each other, either partially or fully.

Comment: ARM Cortex-M parts have a single address space, but as a speed optimization distinct implementation mechanisms and internal data paths for the different types of storage.  The same could be argued effectively be true for any modern large system with distinct instruction and data caches.

Comment: An example of a 'hybrid' Harvard architecture is PIC24. It has a "PSV" feature (Program Space Visibility) which allows program memory to be partially mapped in to the upper 32K region of SRAM. It can then be used as a ROM. The SRAM bus is only 16-bit wide though, but given the typical RAM size of these devices that poses not a problem.

Comment: I think the simplest way to describe a hybrid architecture would be to say that there exists an area of code memory with a fast bus connecting it to the instruction-processing logic, and another area of data memory with a fast bus connecting it to the data-processing logic, but there are other--possibly slower--communications paths allowing data to travel other ways (most typically between the code memory and data-processing unit or--in some caching scenarios--from the data memory to a code memory cache).

Answer (score 4):

Dave has already mentioned the differences between [Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) and [von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) architectures.

An example of a von Neumann architecture, where there is just one address space for RAM, Flash, I/O and EEPROM, is the HCS08 family from Freescale.  Here is the memory map of one of its microcontrollers that has 128K of Flash and 4K of RAM:

[image]

Note in this figure, memory address 0 is at the top.  It is also not to scale; the address 0x8000 (32K boundary) should be exactly in the middle.

This microcontroller has a direct page (sometimes called page 0), i.e. 256 addresses which can be accessed with just an 8-bit address (which reduces the size of the instruction by a byte).  The first 128 locations, 0x0000 to 0x007F are used to map I/O registers.  This is followed by the 5K of RAM, from address 0x0080 to 0x17FF.  By doing this, the first 128 bytes of RAM are also located in page 0.  This is followed 256 additional addressed reserved for additional I/O registers at 0x1800 to 0x18FF, then more RAM, then the first segment of Flash, then 2K of EEPROM.

Then additional pages of Flash.  Note they have page numbers too (PPAGE).  Remember I said this microcontroller has 128K of Flash?  How do you fit that into 64K of address space?  By using paged addressing.  There is a "paging window" at 0x8000 to 0xBFFF (16K) where one of eight 16K pages of Flash (128K total) can be mapped.  Which one is controlled by a paging register. When the compiler is generating jumps or subroutine calls, it knows to update the paging register as needed.

Some of the pages can also be addressed directly (PPAGES 0, 1, and 3) without using the paging register.  This is needed for things like interrupt handlers, which may occur at any time.  Common subroutines, like the C library, are also good candidates for these pages.

Not shown are the reset and interrupt vectors, which start and the top of memory (0xFFFF) and go down.

Pure Harvard architecture machines have much simpler schemes, there is one address space for Flash starting at 0x0000, another for RAM starting also at 0x0000 and still another for I/O ports starting at 0x0000 (sometimes RAM and I/O are put together in the same space, known as memory-mapped I/O).  If I/O ports are used, they acre accessed via special instructions such as IN and OUT.

Because they are separate spaces, they can have different widths.  The PIC16 microcontroller from Microchip for example, has a 14-bit instruction width and 8 bit RAM and I/O busses.

What's the advantage of each?  Well with a Harvard architecture, you can have 64K of program space, 64K of RAM space, and 64K of I/O space, all using 16-bit addresses.  So it's good for 8 and 16-bit microcontrollers.  Because the program is in Flash, it can't be modified.

With von Neumann architectures, you can run programs out of either Flash (or ROM) and RAM.  This is how PC's work: when they first start up, they boot up using a BIOS (Basic Input/Output System) ROM, which reads the OS off of a hard drive and loads it into RAM.  From then on, programs execute out of RAM.

There are also "[modified Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture)" processors, which allow part of the instruction space to be viewed as if it were "read-only" RAM.  This is usually done using a paging window similar to the one in the HCS08 diagram earlier.  In the PIC24, this feature is called Program Space Visibility (PSV).

Comment: Though I feel it to be a little difficult to understand the address spacing described in the first part, it answered most of my doubts surrounding this topic.